# PHP if functions based on input information not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

Basically I'm pulling information from a form, and I want to echo different things based on a user's input. However, I'm only ever getting the first result. How can I fix this? Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHide() {
            var div = document.getElementById("hidden");
            if (div.style.display == 'none') {
                 div.style.display = '';
            }
            else {
            }   
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'post.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                    alert('form was submitted');
                    }   
                });
            e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="t0i"><input type="submit" onclick="showHide();">
    </form>
    <div style="display:none;" id="hidden">
        <?php
        $t0 = $_POST["t0i"];
        if ($t0 = "1") {
            echo "result 1";
        }
        elseif ($t0 = "2") {
            echo "result 2";
        }
        elseif ($t0 = "3") {
            echo "result 3";
        }
        else {
            echo "no result, try again";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

The javascript is essential, it's showing the hidden result (display:none;) on submit and the second script is ensuring that the page does not refresh after submitting the form (everything is done on the same page). Removing both these scripts, however, does not solve my problem. I have a feeling the issue is in the PHP, but I can't figure out what it is. Thanks in advance. Here is a demo:

Comment: Your if condition must be with '==' not '='

Answer (score 3):

Here you are :)

```
 if ($t0 = "1")
```

correct:

```
if ($t0 == "1")
```

Comment: Sometimes this mistake job me crazy)))

Comment: Now I keep getting the "no result" (else)... What have I got wrong?

Comment: Ok, try just to print the $_POST["t0i"] and make sure it has the expected value
var_dump($_POST["t0i"])

Answer (score 0):

Like Sergey pointed out, you need to use double equals signs for comparisons. Please have a look at the man page:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: Now I keep getting the "no result" (else)... What have I got wrong?

Comment: Could you post your new code? I can take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

The operator = used for assign value.The operator == casts between two different types if they are different, while the === operator performs a 'typesafe comparison'. That means that it will only return true if both operands have the same type and the same value.

Examples:

```
$a = 1; // assign value
1 === 1: true
1 == 1: true
1 === "1": false // 1 is an integer, "1" is a string
1 == "1": true // "1" gets casted to an integer, which is 1
"foo" === "foo": true // both operands are strings and have the same value
```

**you can uesd switch statement**

**Switch** : The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece of code depending on which value it equals to.

```
   $t0 = $_POST["t0i"];
   switch ($t0) {
        case 1:
             echo "result 1";
            break;
        case 2:
             echo "result 2";
            break;
        case 3:
             echo "result 3";
            break;
        default:
            echo "no result, try again";
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Now I keep getting the "no result" (else)... What have I got wrong?

Comment: Using the switch statement continues to give me "no result, try again"

Comment: what is value of $_POST["t0i"]?

Comment: The text input with name="t0i" in the form (method="post"). If I enter '1' into the input, I would like to receive 'result 1', and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I have Checked using Firebug  it gives  Undefined index: t0i 
and post is not assigning the value. So no condition is fullfilled so your are getting no result.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHide() {
            var div = document.getElementById("hidden");
            if (div.style.display == 'none') {
                 div.style.display = '';
            }
            else {
            }   
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            var val=$('#t0i').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'form.php',
                    data:{val:val},

                    success: function (data) {
        if (val == "1"){
             $('#hidden').html("result 1");
        }
        else if (val== "2"){
             $('#hidden').html("result 2");
        }
        else if (val == "3") {
            $('#hidden').html("result 3");
        }
        else {
            $('#hidden').html("no result, try again"); 
        }

                    }   
                });
            e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input id="t0i" type="text" name="t0i"><input type="submit" onclick="showHide();">
    </form>
    <div style="display:none;" id="hidden">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So how would I resolve the issue?

Comment: the above coding is working as you want.